# Jetpack Compose Material 3 and Material 2 theming

Tags: android, material-ui, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3

My app uses Material 3; however, I'm also using some libraries that use Material 2. The problem is: to get colors with Material 3 you have to use `MaterialTheme.colorScheme`, but to get them with Material 2 you have to use `MaterialTheme.colors`. So, the libraries that use Material 2 use `MaterialTheme.colors`, but when I create my theme I use `MaterialTheme.colorScheme`:

```kotlin
val DarkColorScheme = darkColorScheme(
    primary = Green,
    secondary = Blue,
    tertiary = Red,
    onSurface = Color.White,
    error = Red,
)

@Composable
fun StarDictTheme(
    darkTheme: Boolean = true,
    // Dynamic color is available on Android 12+
    dynamicColor: Boolean = true,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    MaterialTheme(
        colorScheme = DarkColorScheme,
        typography = Typography,
        content = content
    )
}
```

So, in the end the libraries don't use my theme colors, and I get dark elements on a dark background.

Is it possible to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at: https://github.com/daniyaljavaid/ThemingInCompose. This might help you passing your theme.